# Is it possible to change sky texture in UWP MapControl?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-maps

UWP MapControl shows stars and the sun at some random place on the sky like in the image below. Is it any way to hide them or any possibility to play with sky texture?

I have played with the MapStyleSheet editor and I have no clue how to do it.

[image]

Comment: I can't find any document to tell how to change  sky texture in UWP MapControl, I need do more researching to confirm this, If I have any updates, I will comment below.

Comment: Currently, there is no such api could edit the sky texture, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app, or post it in WInUI issue box [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the request/proposal list.

Comment: Do you means you don't know how to post request ?

Comment: No, no. I mean that I didn't know that there was such a forum or place to send proposals and request. Sorry for my english

Comment: You could open your os and input feedback hub in searchbox where in the task bar, then launch the app, find suggest a feature button.

Answer (score 1):

There are some limited customization options available for the sky. I recommend you use the Map Stylesheet editor application available here to explore them:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/map-style-sheet-editor/9nbhtcjt72ft
You can turn off the atmosphere effect, and control the color of the space background.
I don't think there's any way to turn off the sun/stars.
Documentation on how to use the stylesheet to customize the view is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/elements-of-map-style-sheet and the Stylesheet editor application will generate sample code for you.

Comment: I've already played with fog, atmosphere and space color, and as it can be seen in the picture above, I can hide a little bit the stars, but nothing more.